# SPWorkflowTaskProperties.AssignedTo and "1;#Alice Jackson" format

Tags: .net, sharepoint, task

I am new to SharePoint. Sorry if answer to my question is obvious.

I can't understand, how to assign Task to user programmatically. I set properties in SPWorkflowTaskProperties, all properties pass to Task, but string property AssignedTo doesn't.

```
//next variants don't works
TaskProperty.AssignedTo = "1;#Michael Pushin";
TaskProperty.AssignedTo = "Michael Pushin";    
TaskProperty.ExtendedProperties["Assigned To"] = "1;#Michael Pushin";
```

I am trying to realize delegation pattern. For it I read information from list item that have field type Person.

```
SPList functList = thisWeb.Lists["Functions"];
SPListItem functItem = functList.GetItemById(1);
object person = functItem["Default Assignee"];
string assignee = person.ToString();
//At this point assignee equals "1;#Michael Pushin"
```

When I set the "Assigned To" field by hands and read programmatically it value equals to "1;#Michael Pushin" too.

How can I set "Assigned To" field programmatically from value of the person variable?

Thank you in advance.

PS: sorry for my writing. English is not my native language.

PPS: SharePoint 2010.

Comment: When I set TaskProperty.AssignedTo = "MYDOMAIN\\michael.pushin" all works, but how can I convert data from "1;#Michael Pushin" format to suitable? TaskProperty.AssignedTo = "MYDOMAIN\\Michael Pushin" does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not convert person to string.

```
object person = functItem["Default Assignee"];
```

At this point person is smth like SPFieldUserValue. Cast to the actual type and see if you're able to get SPUser out of it and then grab the SPUser.Login.

Comment: No, at this point actual type of object person is already string. May be exists another way to get item in smth like SPFieldUserValue type? Or How can I lookup for it? May be I have to use ID=1 (**1**;#Michael Pushin) to obtain it by lookup, but where?

Comment: var login = (new SPFieldUserValue(spWeb, asignee)).User.Login;

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution!
Thanks to this post: http://blogs.windowsclient.net/mortezanaeimabadi/archive/2011/09/17/how-to-obtain-spuser-object-from-values-such-as-quot-27-morteza-quot.aspx

```
SPFieldUserValue  userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.web, functItem["Default Assignee"].ToString());
SPUser userObject = userValue.User;
string asignee=userObject.ToString();
//hurray! asignee="MYDOMAIN\\michael.pushin"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work while setting the assigned user through a workflow:

```
         taskProperties.AssignedTo = workflowProperties.OriginatorUser.LoginName;
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
SPFieldUserValue  userValue = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.web,     
functItem["Default Assignee"].ToString());
SPUser userObject = userValue.User;
string asignee=userObject.ToString()
```

thanks Mikhail!

Comment: Hey Jase, this should really be a comment.